# Rails 4: How to Use Send to Build Conditional Asset Tag Helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I want to render asset tag helpers according to asset mime-types, using `send` to cast that file type like this:

```
<% if @cloud_file.filetype.match(/^(audio|image|video)$/) %>
  <%= send("#{@cloud_file.filetype}_tag") @cloud_file.url %>
<% end %>
```

Sadly, Rails does not seem OK with this approach and returns  a syntax error! Anyone knows what is wrong with this code or how to build tag helpers according to asset type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd make a helper that handles this logic for you, like:

```
def build_tag(file)
  case file.filetype
   when 'audio'
     content_tag(:div ...)
   when 'image'
     content_tag(:img ...)
   when 'audio'
     content_tag(:div, class: audio ...)
  end
end
```

And then in your view simply call

```
<% if @cloud_file.filetype.match(/^(audio|image|video)$/) %>
  <%= build_tag(@cloud_file) %>
<% end %>
```

You could even clean this up a bit and add a method to check the filetype to your `@cloud_file` class:

```
def is_embeddable?
  filetype.match(/^(audio|image|video)$/)
end
```

So your final code looks like:

```
<% if @cloud_file.is_embeddable? %>
  <%= build_tag(@cloud_file) %>
<% end %>
```